# getting soap:Fault while consuming a soap service

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have a soap client which consumes a remote soap service. Everything is fine with the connection and setup. when I send a soap request, I get a soap fault message as following:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Index: 0, Size: 0</faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I am really having hard time understanding such error message. just for the fact, I know everything is fine with the request envelope. Could anyone please help me understand this error.

Here is the SOAP request Envelope:

```
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
   <ns2:createRequest xmlns:ns2="http://request.services.xyz.com/">
   <hid>1234</hid>
   <requestTypeCode>APPOINT_REQ</requestTypeCode>
   <createdBy>testuser</createdBy>
   <assignedTo>testuser</assignedTo>
   <data>
    <dataField>
     <name>ContentText</name>
     <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">Test!</value>
    </dataField>
    <dataField>
     <name>Date</name>
     <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2013-12-09T13:28:34.009-05:00</value>
    </dataField>
    <dataField>
     <name>OrderNumber</name>
     <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:string">1-123432</value>
    </dataField>
   </data>
  <originAppCode>ABCD</originAppCode>
 </ns2:createRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is the method signature which I am trying to invoke with the SOAP request.

```
public @XmlElement(name="Request")Request createRequest( @WebParam(name="hid")int hid, @WebParam(name="requestTypeCode")String requestTypeCode, @WebParam(name="createdBy")String createdBy, 
        @WebParam(name="assignedTo")String assignedTo, @WebParam(name="createTime")Date createTime, @WebParam(name="data")DataFields data, @WebParam(name="originAppCode") String originAppCode) throws Exception;
```

here is the part of wsdl :

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://request.services.xyz.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="requestServiceImplService" targetNamespace="http://request.services.xyz.com/">
 <wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" version="1.0">
   <xs:complexType final="#all" name="stringArray">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
  <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://request.services.xyz.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://request.services.xyz.com/" version="1.0">
   <xs:element name="createRequest" type="tns:createRequest"/>
   <xs:element name="createRequestResponse" type="tns:createRequestResponse"/>
   <xs:element name="dataFields" type="tns:dataFields"/>
   <xs:complexType name="createRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="hid" type="xs:int"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="requestTypeCode" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createdBy" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="assignedTo" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="createTime" type="xs:dateTime"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="data" type="tns:dataFields"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="originAppCode" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="createRequestResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:request"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="dataFields">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="dataField" type="tns:dataField"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="dataField">
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
     <xs:element name="value" type="xs:anyType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </wsdl:types>
 <wsdl:message name="createRequest">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:createRequest" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="createRequestResponse">
  <wsdl:part element="tns:createRequestResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:operation name="createRequest">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:createRequest" name="createRequest"></wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:createRequestResponse" name="createRequestResponse">    </wsdl:output>
 </wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:binding name="RequestServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:IRequestService">
 <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
 <wsdl:operation name="createRequest">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
   <wsdl:input name="createRequest">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </wsdl:input>
   <wsdl:output name="createRequestResponse">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
   </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="RequestServiceImplService">
 <wsdl:port binding="tns:RequestServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="RequestServiceImplPort">
  <soap:address location="location_where_service_is_being_hosted/cxf/jaxws/RequestService"/>
 </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: could you please paste the request you are sending

Comment: I just edited the question and added it above. sorry for not adding it before.

Comment: @Ashish , could you also check what all exceptions you are getting at your server side.

Comment: I have attached part of the wsdl here. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Messages like `Index: 0, Size: 0` are often caused by `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s.

In you're case that could mean:

- The request is empty.
- The request has the wrong encoding.
- Security mechanisms won't let your request through.
- There is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the backend.

**Next steps:**

Check if your server accepts requests from [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org).

- You have full control over the request, so if something goes wrong, it's probably an error in the backend.
- If it works, there's a problem in your client. Check the request your client is sending. Is it complete? Does it contain unreadable characters?

---

***Result:*** That error also occurs when using SoapUI.

**XML / XML Schema**

Some things in the XML and XML Schema attracted my attention.

- In the request only `createRequest` uses a namespace. The other elements don't have a namespace, because they don't specify a namespace prefix. Using `<createRequest xmlns="http://request.services.xyz.com/">` would assign a default namespace to all elements below `createRequest`.
- (In XML Schema there is a reference to `type="tns:dataFields"` although there is only `dataField`. Also `createRequest` is lower case while in the request it's written with camel case. I assume both are not real problems, because you changed the names for StackOverflow.)

**Server error**

Since it's not possible to send any request the server accepts (not even with SoapUI), you definitly have to debug the server.

- Is there any error message in the log?
- Where does the Exception occur? Set a break point on `java.lang.Exception` and narrow it down until you find the problem.

Comment: does soap:Server means the error is from server side. just for a note , the service does access the database at its backend. I tried the same request envelope with SoapUI but I got the same error.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, those were my mistakes. I just edited the wsdl so that nobody gets confused. I looked in the server logs. I found the same error there "IndexOutOfBoundException". Thanks

Comment: Hi, I was able to figure out the issue. the value of "requestTypeCode"  which I was sending in SOAP request did not exist in the Database and since that typeCode couldnt be mapped within any values in Database table, it sent IndexOutOfBound Exception. Thanks a lot for helping me debug the issue.